# Retrieve data inside txt file to use it php script

Tags: php

I have a txt file ('realtime.txt') containing data from a weather station. The values are separated by a blank space and look like this:

```
02/02/19 11:50:10 11.1 60 3.6 23.6 19.4 338 0.0 1.5 1021.4 NNW +0.3 -1.4 ...
```

I would like to retrive each one of these values and assing it to a variable, to be echoed when needed in a php script. Using the same order those variables would be something like this:

```
$udate $utime $temp $hum $dew $wspeed $wlatest $bearing $rrate $rfall $press $currentwdir $ptrend $ttrend ...
```

With my begginner's php knowledge I managed to do it with a very odd solution that I am sure will make any php expert smile but... it's working if... :-)
if number of characters doesn't change!!! 
If for instance, temperature changes from 11.9ºC to 9.5ºC everything gets messed up because there is one character less when counting!

```
<?php 

// starting from caracter n read following i bytes
$udate = file_get_contents('realtime.txt', FALSE, NULL, 0, 8); 
$utime = file_get_contents('realtime.txt', FALSE, NULL, 9, 8); 
$temp = file_get_contents('realtime.txt', FALSE, NULL, 18, 4); 

// ...

echo 'updated @: '.$udate.' '.$utime.'<br>'; 
echo 'temperature is: '.$temp.'&deg;C<br>'; 

// ...
```

Could anyone please teach me how to do this the way a php expert would do?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the looks of it you can just explode on space and use list() to set the array to each variable.

```
list($udate, $utime, $temp, $hum, $dew, $wspeed, $wlatest, $bearing, $rrate, $rfall, $press, $currentwdir, $ptrend, $ttrend) = explode(" ", file_get_contents('realtime.txt'));
```

The order of the parameters in list should match what order the values are in the file.

---

An alternative method is to keep the array as an array but make is associative.

```
$keys = ['udate', 'utime', 'temp', 'hum', 'dew', 'wspeed', 'wlatest', 'bearing', 'rrate', 'rfall', 'press', 'currentwdir', 'ptrend', 'ttrend'];
$arr = array_combine($keys, explode(" ", file_get_contents('realtime.txt')));

echo $arr['udate']; //02/02/19
```

This means you can loop through the values and use a single line of code to output all values.

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    echo $key . " is " . $val;
}
// udate is 02/02/19
// utime is 11:50:10
// temp is 11.1
// And so on
```

As you can see what you set the as the name in the $keys array is what is displayed.
So if you set "Date updated" as key you will get a nicer output.

Comment: Thank you sooo much Andreas! it looks perfect and I am going to try it. The txt file has 58 keys so it will take me some time to rename them all to use your approach for a nicer output. I will let you know the resul later on.

Comment: It may not always be appropriate with the second method now that I think about it. Since you can't add "degrees Celsius" for example.

Comment: Thank you once again Andreas! The 2 solutions you presented here are exactly what I was looking for! However I do prefer #1, because it is much easier to echo single values (temperature, humidity, windspeed, etc) just when they are needed in the script. For other guys that will use #1 method, there is a coma missing in `explode(" " file_get_contents('realtime.txt'));` It should be `explode(" " , file_get_contents('realtime.txt'));` Once again Andreas, thank you soooo much you can't imagine how happy I am now :-)